# Comment disappeared?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

I'm fairly sure I made another comment on the accepted answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813278/how-to-compute-mean-average-robustly).  However, it no longer appears on the question page.  What happened?

Comment: It may well have been deleted.  Without even knowing what the comment was, we can't really even theorize as to why it might have been deleted.  There are tons of reasons for deleting comments.

Comment: Someone flagged it as rude/offensive. A mod handled the flag by deleting it. Given that comments are things you can expect to go away at any moment, well...

Comment: @Oded: Gotcha.  Is there someplace where I'd get notifications about such things?  (Also, I guess you should post that as an answer since it, well, answers the question.)

Comment: Happend to my for my comment too.The comment said "How was temperature in Prime 95 before it failed of rust" or something on this answer   http://superuser.com/a/1087670/544148

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone flagged it as rude/offensive. A mod handled the flag by deleting it.

Given that comments are things you can expect to go away at any moment, well...

---

Comments are and have always been "second hand citizens" of the Stack Exchange universe. We see them as ways to help to community communicate with someone who posted a question or answer in order to expand and clarify it.

Comments that do so are expected to get integrated into the post.

Comments were never meant as means for idle chit-chat, banter (constructive or otherwise) and such.

Given these two points: integration of **important**  information into the post and that pretty much any other kind of comment goes against the specific reason for their existence, any and each comment is fair game - here today, gone tomorrow.

In short: if the information in a comment is important to the post - **integrate it**, don't let it languish where it may be removed without notice.

---

This nature of comments is why we do not notify of their deletion. Comment deletion is to be expected.