# Tendency to answer with comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm noticing a trend towards answering with comments - maybe related to [It's easy to robo-review questions and answers with comments!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260220/its-easy-to-robo-review-questions-and-answers-with-comments) or similar comments.

I feel this causes confusion:

- The OP has no clear way to accept the comment as answer, except asking the commenter to copy it to a 'full' answer
- The comments are not counted as answer in the questions list, and as such waste time
- Even though correct - and even upvoted, it is difficult to detect right answers in comments, more so if they disappear in the 'more comments' category

Shouldn't a mechanism to promote a correct comment to a full-fledged answer (by the OP, or by moderators) be useful?

Comment: See also [Why is answering in comments trending](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272642/why-answering-in-comments-is-trending), and [Answerers who only use comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)

Comment: Thanks for the extra links, particularly the second one, Michael. I did visit the top 'related questions' but those weren't listed. Glad to find other people have noticed the same...

Comment: Questioners are not holding up their end, the majority are just not interested in creating useful Q+A and only came here to pick up an answer to their helpdesk question.  Answers in comments are the result.  The odds of bringing back "minimum effort" as a requirement for a Q seem remote.

Comment: I do it all the time because I can head a person in the right direction without taking the five to ten minutes to construct a worthy answer. Oh, look, I just did it again.  You'll have to suffer, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't a mechanism to promote a correct comment to a full-fledged answer (by the OP, or by moderators) be useful?

No, this shouldn't be a thing. You can already copy/paste a comment to make it an answer, and that shouldn't be encouraged. If you want to convert a comment to an answer, you should take the time to flesh it out to make it a full answer.

Comment: "should" is not a valid answer for a web site that (at this writing) is attracting newbies in droves. Far friendlier to make adaptations to the way people work, if at all possible. Such adaptations could gently encourage users to do things more ideally. Besides which, insisting that something done improperly be carved into stone (effectively), without any option to change it, is frankly impractical. People often do things the wrong way. We should acknowledge and adapt to this.

Comment: @AlexHall You're the one suggesting that something done improperly should be carved into stone. If you give people a button to easily convert a comment into an answer, they'll click it. Then you'll have "droves" of half-formed thoughts posted as answers instead of comments. The system isn't currently broken, this proposal is.

Comment: I meant that an insistence that something should be done a certain way, carved into stone, is frankly impractical where people do things another way, whatever you tell them to do. I stand by that. Also, "improperly" (and "this proposal is [broken]") is subjective. Let's admit this is subjective, ok? If we can't, it's futile hot air. Your assertion that this would lead to droves of half-formed answers cites no precedent, because there is none. Nobody knows what this *would* do. How about testing it small-scale, examining how it *could* work? Maybe upgraded comments could get less merit, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

We can't stop users from writing answers in the comments. We can inform them ("Avoid answering questions in comments"), and you can flag comments, but that's about it.

We don't like comments, we treat them like [second class citizens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255824/1043380). Have you been on a phpbb forum searching for the answer to a problem? It's terrible to have to go through pages and pages of "I need help too" and "thank, solved it for me" posts. There's usually no way to highlight the *actual answer*. That's the goal we have here: cut down on comments so we can highlight answers.

Should we have a way to "promote" a comment to an answer?

Automatically: no.

If the user wrote the answer in the wrong place, it's his/her loss. *You* can go ahead and write your own complete answer, in the answers section. You can even link to the comment where your information is based off of.

If you feel so inclined, you can make the answer a "Community Wiki" post, which has less editing restrictions and does not give reputation to anyone.

So, in short: If someone made a good comment that is "answer quality", the community should edit it into an existing answer (if applicable) or make it a new answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering! 'it's his/her loss.' That doesn't seem correct to me - I thought main purpose of this forum was to help people. Loosing an answer in comments helps the OP of the message, but very few other people, leading to duplicates. And I didn't say 'automatically'. I proposed to give the OP of the thread the possibility to promote it, without cut/paste/etc.

Comment: What I mean by "his loss" is "he/she missed the opportunity to write a full answer, and thus missed out on the ability to earn rep and other rewards."

Comment: One of the (minor) annoyances of the comments, is that pressing the Enter key publishes the comment. I'm used to separating my texts in paragraphs, and as such instinctively press Enter frequencly. My apologies for sending the incomplete comment.

Comment: You're thinking of comments in the wrong way. It's not for conversation. There are no line breaks. Remember we are a question and answer site. Comments only exist to help polish the questions and answers, and should be removed once they have done their job.

Comment: Frankly, telling people what they should do without offering adaptations to help solve the underlying problem (that it isn't going to be immediately obvious to a lot of users how to answer questions properly--or it is obvious, but they don't care to) is *futile*. I'm tempted to say it's arrogant. Bosses order people around. Users in a public space who are strangers bossing each other around? Bad idea. Yes, we could suggest suggest people do things properly, or that it's their loss if they don't, but the tone of this answer is rather insistently bossy. Also, "that's their loss" is careless.